# Why does a sequence which diverges to infinity not have a convergent subsequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I came across this question and I thought that the sequence:

$1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, ..$ would diverge to infinity as it is basically the natural numbers with $1$ sandwiched in between. Surely the subsequence of all the even indexed elements would converge to 1?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that a sequence diverges to $\infty$? I don't think that yours does, by any reasonable definition.

Comment: By definition $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ diverges to infinity if and only if for each $a\in\Bbb R$ there is an $n_a\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\ge a$ for all $n\ge n_a$. Your sequence does not satisfy that condition.

Comment: Another way to say that $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ diverges to $\infty$ is that for each $r\in \Bbb R,$ the set $\{n\in \Bbb N: x_n\le r\}$ is finite.

Comment: Yeah I was using the general definition for divergence not the one for divergence to infinity :/